# Can Magic Trackpad tap to click be made to work inside Steam games?

Tags: macos, trackpad, magic-trackpad

I am notice some games using Apple Magic Trackpad do not respect tap to click as opposed to the physical button click. I run OS X 10.8.4 and specifically [Endless Space](http://store.steampowered.com/app/208140/) running on Steam fails to respect tap to click. The only click it registers is the click with pressure in the lower area of the apple magic trackpad.

Is there any way to get tap to click to work inside the games?

Comment: Someone have mercy, I have this exact problem!

Comment: Can you still reproduce this in a specific game once you've ruled out things like [low battery in the trackpad](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/62629/how-to-fix-the-jerky-and-jumpy-apple-magic-trackpad-behavior)?

Comment: Same darn problem here. You have to click the trackpad unfortunately, which is a little maddening. It's only Endless Space, I don't have the problem with other games like Portal or Civ 5.

Comment: Same issue here with many, if not most, games, including standalone titles, not only Steam.

Comment: @bmike [Don't Starve](http://www.dontstarvegame.com/) for example, both Steam and standalone have this issue. They also mention this on the game forum, but there's no solution so far http://forums.kleientertainment.com/topic/25125-gameplay-mac-trackpad-compatibility/.